# Como evitar ter que fazer referência ao EF?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, arquitetura-de-software

Olá, todos.

Tenho, basicamente, uma camada de acesso a dados com EF6 e outra de apresentação (Asp.Net WebApi). Não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar sem que a camada de apresentação faça referência ao EF. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Minha solução atualmente está assim:

```
Core       - sem dependências
Domain     - depende da Core
DataAccess - depende da Core, Domain e EF
WebApi     - depende da Core, Domain e DataAccess (e EF, mas não deveria)
```

Não há nenhuma classe pública na DataAccess que exponha alguma dependência do EF (DbContext, DbSet, etc). Ao invés, há um conjunto de classes próprias de fachada (façade).

Sem referência nenhuma ocorre esta exceção na primeira linha de código que faz acesso aos dados:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException]
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework'
section of the application config file.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

Adicionando a seção do EF no Web.config (mas sem referenciar o EF) esta outra exceção ocorre logo na instanciação do DbContext:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException]
The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer'
registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
```

Comment: Certamente você esta acessando a camada de dados diretamente sem usa o [di (dependency injection)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia)

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Algum exemplo?
A camada DataAccess não expõe nenhuma classe do EF.

Comment: http://desenvolvedor.ninja/inversao-de-controle-e-injecao-de-dependencia-no-asp-net-core/

Comment: http://desenvolvedor.ninja/dryioc-inversao-de-controle-e-injecao-de-dependencia-no-net/

Comment: Não estou desenvolvendo Asp.Net Core nem EF Core. Estou com o Framework 4.7.1 e EF6.

Comment: isso funciona para qualquer versão

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não é possível. A aplicação em execução (seja uma Web API, um WPF, um Console, ou até mesmo um projeto de teste) precisa ter o EF instalado (mesmo utilizando DI), e não entendo porque isso seria um problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fim, cheguei a uma solução que satisfaz o cenário.

## A causa

Como o Entity Framework 6.x depende de uma seção de configuração no .config para definição do provedor de acesso e esta, por sua vez, é *tipada* com classes da própria biblioteca, a referência torna-se necessária em todas as camadas subsequentes da solução.

```xml
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

## A solução

Resolvi migrar para o [EF Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) por ver que as configurações de provedores e todas as demais não são definidas em arquivos de configuração, o que possibilita um maior desacoplamento entre camadas. Daí é só precisei escrever classes de encapsulamento das funcionalidades de acesso a dados que quero expor (camada DataService).

Criei um [repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/erikcordeiro/EFCoreTrainning) com um protótipo bem simplificado dessa arquitetura.